# Unwrapping array types recursively in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, typing

I need to create a function that can get a very "dynamic" parameter. it should be a ble to accept many types of arrays

```
class NdArray<T> {

}

// need to be able to get

f(number[]) // -> NdArray<number>
f(number[][]) // -> NdArray<number>
f(number[][][]) // -> NdArray<number>
//and so on...
f(string[]) // -> NdArray<string>
f(string[][]) // -> NdArray<string>
f(string[][][]) // -> NdArray<string>
// and generally
f(object[][][]...) // -> NdArray<object>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to describe what you've tried, or any references or resources you've found that have gotten you close to your solution. I also recommend using a more descriptive title (e.g. "unwrapping array types of arbitrary depth").

Answer (score 4):

Recursively unwrap the array:

```
type UnwrapArray<A> = A extends unknown[] ? UnwrapArray<A[number]> : A;
```

If `A` is an array, we unwrap the type of its elements. Otherwise it's just something else we don't need to unwrap.

Your function `f` here could be something like:

```
function f<T>(type: T): NdArray<UnwrapArray<T>> {
    // a very cool implementation
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgdwE4EMwEEmpAHnQPigF4p0oIAPYCOAEwGcoBXOAazgHsE4BtAXSgB+WIlQYsKXOh5wmAWwBGEJH0IAuUgG4AsACg9tCAGMANiiTQAZiyPAAlhzhRLOACr4AFKEgbXASg14ZDRMbDd8HX1dKGccWUVlfk9+P0iAejSAPUE9GJd4pSR+JI8U9Kyc6NiCxL5i1VK+VL0M7KA)